# Reader(StaxEventItemReader) Resource to Domain object

Tags: jaxb, spring-batch

I want to pass the input resource location as a String to a field of the domain object.
My configuration looks like this:

```
<bean id="step2Reader"
        class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.MultiResourceItemReader">
        <property name="resources" value="file:${step2.reader.resource}/*/*/*.xml"></property>
        <property name="delegate" ref="mainReader"></property>
    </bean>

<bean id="mainReader" class="org.springframework.batch.item.xml.StaxEventItemReader"
        scope="step">
        <property name="fragmentRootElementName" value="Domain" />
        <property name="unmarshaller" ref="domainMarshaller" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="domainMarshaller" class="org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller">
        <property name="classesToBeBound">
            <list>
                <value>com.example.Domain</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

and Domain.java is a JAXB generated class containing a field like this:

```
 @XmlElement(name = "PATH_TO_DOCUMENT", required = true)
 private String pathtodocument;
```

which is supposed to be filled by the input resource as a string.

I've thought of either extending `StaxEventItemReader` to include this functionality or somehow make visible the resource to the `Processor` of the domain and fill the value of field there, but got stuck.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let your `com.example.Domain` object implements [`ResourceAware`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/item/ResourceAware.html) so reader will automagically injects current resource into `Domain` object.

Comment: Forgot to mention that I can not tinker the Domain object. Can the Processor implement this interface and just update the value of the field in Domain object when processing?

Comment: can you extend `Domain` class (as `class DomainWithResource extends Domain implements ResourceAware`) and modify `domainMarshaller` definition in xml? else you can operate during marshal/object creation and create a CGLIB proxy of `Domain` object that implements ResourceAware...

Comment: or extends step2Reader and in `read()` manual set current resource name into Domain.pathtodocument

Comment: Got lucky and was letted to implement ResourceAware in my Domain object and in the setResource method added the input path in pathtodocument, worked like a charm