# How to use getResource of MultiResourceItemReader

Tags: spring-batch

I am a Spring batch newbie.I have a simple FlatFileReader wrapped in a multiresource item reader. I then write the details in a record in the database. I need to write the filename on every record. Please help me find the simplest way to do this. I know there is getResource method in MultiResourceItemReader class but how to use it please?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reader(StaxEventItemReader) Resource to Domain object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23359814/readerstaxeventitemreader-resource-to-domain-object)

Answer (score 0):

Make the item you're returning from the `FlatFileItemReader` implement `ResourceAware` and the `MultiResourceItemReader` will inject it for you.  You can read more about `ResourceAware` in the javadoc here: http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/item/ResourceAware.html

Comment: The problem is that i return a table of String (String[]).

Comment: Create a wrapper class that implements `ResourceAware`.