# How to get current file name and end of file in Item Processor in Spring Batch?

Tags: spring, spring-batch

I am reading multiple .csv files from a location using multi file reader and I need names of the file in the ItemProcessor for all the input csv files.

Is there a way I can get to know in ItemProcessor that current file is completed?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23359814/readerstaxeventitemreader-resource-to-domain-object/23360080#23360080

Answer (score -3):

you need to set the commitInterval value to 1 so the process will be relaunched with each untreated file in the directory

```
<bean id="simpleStep"        class="org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleStepFactoryBean">
        <property name="commitInterval" value="1" />
</bean>
```

you need to code your custom itemProcessor 
 public class CustomItemProcessor implements ItemProcessor {

```
public Object process(Object arg0) throws Exception {

    File input = (File) arg0;

    // treat your file here 
    System.out.println("File Name : " + input.getName ());
    return input;
}
```

}